# how to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 on centos 6

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, centos6, wkhtmltoimage

How can [wkhtmltoimage 0.12.0](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) be installed on centos amd64? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build it from source.  You need a debian/ubuntu system to do this. (Get a free amazon ec2 or something).  Once you download from the git repo, you run this command:

```
sudo python scripts/build.py setup-schroot-centos6
```

And then:

```
python scripts/build.py centos6-amd64
```

If you're not on a debian-based system, you'll get  "This can only be run on a Debian/Ubuntu distribution, aborting."  Otherwise, it will install a big list of rpms etc to emulate the CentOS environment, and then the second command will build.

Comment: The 0.12.1 release has official CentOS 6 RPMs, so this is not needed.

Comment: This can only be run on a Debian/Ubuntu distribution, aborting.

Answer (score -1):

Use the CentOS 5 binaries for the [0.12.1-dev](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopdf/files/0.12.1-dev/) build linked from the website.